# How to Create a Pig Latin Job in Azure HDInsight Cluster

Tags: azure, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I just created a free account to Azure and created a hadoop cluster on HDInsight. However, it dose not in anyway show how to launch a Pig client and create pig latin job and run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Ambari UI to run pig latin jobs.

**Note:** To process data using Pig, will need to open an SSH console that is connected to your cluster and then run the pig latin using local mode or mapreduce mode:

> **If you are using a Windows client computer:**

1. In the Microsoft Azure portal, on the HDInsight Cluster blade for your HDInsight cluster, click  Secure Shell, and then in the Secure Shell blade, in the Hostname list, note the Host name for your cluster (which should be your_cluster_name-ssh.azurehdinsight.net).
2. Open PuTTY, and in the Session page, enter the host name into the Host Name box. Then under Connection type, select SSH and click Open. If a security warning that the host certificate cannot be verified is displayed, click Yes to continue.
3. When prompted, enter the SSH username and password you specified when provisioning the cluster (not the cluster login username).

> **If you are using a Mac OS X or Linux client computer:**

1. In the Microsoft Azure portal, on the HDInsight Cluster blade for your HDInsight cluster, click Secure Shell, and then in the Secure Shell blade, in the Hostname list, select the hostname for your cluster. then copy the ssh command that is displayed, which should resemble the following command – you will use this to connect to the head node. 
   ssh sshuser@your_cluster_name-ssh.azurehdinsight.net
2. Open a new terminal session, and paste the ssh command, specifying your SSH user name (not the cluster login username).
3. If you are prompted to connect even though the certificate can’t be verified, enter yes.
4. When prompted, enter the password for the SSH username.

Once you connected to your cluster, to [run pig latin](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/pig/piglatin_ref1.html#Running+Pig+Latin) as shown:

[image]

You can execute Pig Latin statements:

- Using grunt shell or command line
- In mapreduce mode or local mode
- Either interactively or in batch

**Reference:** [Pig Manual](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/pig/piglatin_ref1.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it is enormously appreciated. I have now successfully created pig latin jobs and run it by following your instructions above.